# Why my Go net.Conn is not cast to custom interface when using httpTrace.ClientTrace{GotConn}

Tags: go

To track connection (in this case, I want to give my connection a name), I wrapped it with a struct `TrackedConn`. This `TrackedConn` implements `HasId` interface and it's expected to return an identifier when call.

However, when I try to cast it to `HasId` interface inside httptrace.ClientTrace{} GotConn, it wasn't valid. I wonder why is that ?

`wrappedAddr` is just to show you that it works.

```golang
type HasId interface {
    Id() string
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: wrapDialContext(&net.Dialer{}),
        },
    }

    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) {

            // this is cast as expected
            if c, ok := (info.Conn.RemoteAddr()).(HasId); ok {
                fmt.Printf("info.Conn.RemoteAddr() HasId: %s\n", c.Id())
            }

            // why is this not cast ?
            if c, ok := (info.Conn).(HasId); ok {
                fmt.Printf("info.Conn HasId: %s\n", c.Id())
            }
        },
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://gobyexample.com", nil)
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))
    ...
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    ...

}

func wrapDialContext(dialer *net.Dialer) func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := dialer.DialContext(ctx, network, address)
        wrappedConn := TrackedConn{
            conn,
            "wrappedConn id",
        }
        return wrappedConn, err
    }
}

type wrappedAddr struct {
    net.Addr
    ident string
}

func (ta wrappedAddr) Id() string {
    return "wrappedAddr id"
}

type TrackedConn struct {
    conn net.Conn
    id   string
}

func (c TrackedConn) Id() string {
    return "TrackedConn id"
}

func (c TrackedConn) RemoteAddr() net.Addr {
    return wrappedAddr{
        Addr:  c.conn.RemoteAddr(),
        ident: c.id,
    }
}

// Other methods to fulfil `net.Conn` interface. It's ok to ignore them.
....
```

Executing them results in

```
info.Conn.RemoteAddr() HasId: wrappedAddr id
```

I expected to see `info.Conn HasId: wrappedConn id"` as well

Full code here : https://play.golang.org/p/05qx45Ub8DH
(Playground is not going to work because of HTTP request)

Comment: Looks like whatever connection gets created by the function produced by a call to `wrapDialContext` gets "wrapped again" with an instance of `*tls.Conn`—because you're accessing a site using the `https://` scheme. I have learned it by using `fmt.Printf("%T\n", info.Conn)` in your tracing code.

Comment: I would say that you also need to override `DialTLSContext` in your `http.Transport`. BTW you can change the scheme of your URL to `http://` and obesrve how the `net/http` stack will chase a redirect to `https://` performed by that site—you will see your type assertion working once but not twice.

Answer (score 2):

To debug your issue, look at the type of `info.Conn` :

```
fmt.Printf("conn type: %T", info.Conn)
```

You are contacting an https server, so the type you get is : `*tls.Conn`.

You need to plug into your `Transport.DialTLSContext()` method.

Comment: heh, that's exactly what @kostix said in his comments (which I only read afterwards)